# what does static signifies in object creation?

Tags: java

```
public static int f(String input) {

     public static Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();

        int n = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {

                if (input.charAt(i) == 'd')
                        stack.push('d');

                else if (input.charAt(i) == 'b') {

                        if (!stack.empty() && stack.pop() == 'd') n++;
                }
        }  

        return n;
}
```

i just want to know the significance of static keyword in object creation...just pasted the whole code here

Comment: A syntax error?  You can't declare a local variable static like that, it won't compile.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't reverse those first two lines somehow?

Comment: The `static` keyword means nothing to the *object creation* of `Stack`, even if you got that code compiling by flipping the first two lines. It means something to the scope of field `stack`, but has no impact whatsoever to the `new Stack<Character>()` call.

Comment: thanks for the answers guys..and yeah first two lines needs to be flipped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What everyone else has said so far is all accurate, but I'll elaborate a bit on your question on what "the significance of static keyword in object creation" is.

Static variables last for the lifetime of the class (so essentially from the start till the end of your program). But in your code, you declare your stack variable inside of a method, so that variable is created and destroyed each time that method is run. Therefore it doesn't actually make any sense to be given the keyword static. These variables are meant to be shared among every instance of the class you create. So you should only create that static variable once when your program is run.

(There are ton of resources elsewhere explaining when/where to use static)

Here are a couple I found useful when learning:

- [stackoverflow link to a similar, but more general discussion on the static keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671496/java-when-to-use-static-methods)
- [A longer but good beginner introduction to all you need to know about the static keyword](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/java/java-for-beginners-static-variables-what-are-they.html)

Answer (score 0):

As @azurefrog says, that won't work - I'm guessing you've copied and pasted the line

```
public static Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
```

from the top of your class for illustrative purposes? If so, you've broken your example in doing so.

Assuming I'm correct and that declaration is from within your class, rather than within that static method, then the answer to your question would be that there will be only a single instance of the `stack` variable, regardless of the number of instances which you create of the class in which it resides: i.e. all instances which you create of your class will  see/contain the same instance of `stack`, and anywhere it is addressed from outside (valid, given that it's public), should be referring to it as `ClassName.stack`, not `instanceName.stack`